# Use same-named aesthetics by default with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sometimes with ggplot I find myself using data frames where the variable names actually correspond to the aesthetics I want to use.  Which leads to code like this:

```
rect <- data.frame(xmin=1,xmax=10,ymin=1,ymax=10)
ggplot(rect, aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))+geom_rect()
```

Feels a bit [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Is there a way to avoid this repetition?

Comment: `ggplot(rect, aes_string(xmin="xmin", xmax="xmax", ymin="ymin", ymax="ymax"))+geom_rect()` This may not reduce the WETness, but slight improvement I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`aes_auto()`, but it's deprecated apparently. Alternatively,

```
aes_all(names(rect))
```

Comment: Nice find. Had no idea that existed.

Comment: Nice ggarchaeology @baptiste!

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: See @baptiste's answer. This is 75% of the functionality of the (now deprecated)  `aes_auto()`.

An even more shortcut-but-`data.frame`-specific alternative to the #spiffy solution by @MrFlick:

```
#' Generate ggplot2 aesthetic mappings from data.frame columns
#' 
#' Use this like you would \code{aes()} or \code{aes_string()} but
#' pass in the \code{data.frame} you want to use for the mapping.
#' By default this will use all the column names from the input
#' \code{data.frame} so use column selections if you don't want 
#' to map them all.
#' 
#' @param df data.frame
aes_from_df <- function(df) {

  mapping <- setNames(as.list(colnames(df)), colnames(df))
  mapping <- lapply(mapping, function(x) {
    if (is.character(x)) parse(text = x)[[1]] else x
  })
  structure(ggplot2:::rename_aes(mapping), class="uneval")

}

rect <- data.frame(xmin=1, xmax=10, ymin=1,  ymax=10)

ggplot(rect, aes_from_df(rect)) + geom_rect()
```

Answer (score 5):

If that really comes up a lot, you could create your own helper function

```
aes_self <- function(...) {
    dots <- as.list(substitute(...()))
    names <- sapply(dots, paste)
    do.call("aes", setNames(dots, names))
}

ggplot(rect, aes_self(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))+geom_rect()
```

And i'll add one more to make it easier to mix fixed aesthetics as well. Here you can use "." to represent a column of the same name as the parameter:

```
aes_dotself <- function(...) {
    dots <- as.list(substitute(...()))
    self <- sapply(dots, function(x) x==as.name("."))
    if(any(self)) {
        dots[self] <- sapply(names(dots[self]), as.name)
    }
    do.call("aes", dots)
}

rect <- data.frame(xmin=1,xmax=10,ymin=1,ymax=10, type="type1")
ggplot(rect, aes_dotself(xmin=.,xmax=.,ymin=.,ymax=., fill=type))+geom_rect()
```